# Increase Activity monitor update frequency to less than a second

Tags: macos, activity-monitor, cpu, history

I want to use the "CPU history" to monitor how some program uses the CPU, but the update frequency of "very often (1 sec)" is not fast enough for me. The changes I want to observe happen in less than a second (I am thinking of 0,1 second).

I would appreciate if someone can tell me if it is possible to go beyond 1 second. Or if there are any other tools that offer faster updates plus a graphical view of the cpu usage history.

Comment: The fastest Activity Monitor ever went was 0.5 seconds. It was back when 10.4 (Tiger) was out. You'll need a different app to get better update frequency.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Thanks for your feedback. Do you have any recommendation for other tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a few options:

1. [Menumeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/), says its incompatible with 10.11 due to code signing restrictions
2. [XRG](http://www.gauchosoft.com/Products/XRG/), an open source Mac resource monitor
3. [Stater](http://apprabica.com/products/osx/stater/), $4.99, available on Mac App Store
4. [Monity](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/monity/id915542151?mt=12), $2.99, great if you want it in Notification Center
5. [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/), $18, tends to be the most popular
6. [System Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/SystemMonitor.html), $4.99, sits in menu bar.

Comment: Menumeters seems to be only a widget for the menubar and not so useful for getting cpu history. But XRG can go up to 0.2 seconds which was good enough for me. Thanks.